# Angularjs ui-router resolve error after first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

Hello I am using resolve to pre-load some data to my state (index), the first time it works ok but when I change state and come back to index I get an error:

```
Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

**index.html**

```
...
resolve:{
  dataPromise: function(data){
    return data.index();
  }
}
...
var dataObj = JSON.parse(dataPromise.data);
```

**data.js**

```
var _getIndex = function () {
  return $resource('content/index').get();
};
```

Comment: if you console.log the data in each case what does it return?

Comment: the second time is undefined

Comment: if you repeatdly hit the endpoint does it cause the same?

Comment: I tried using Postman and it works ok

Comment: are you using factory? is this in the controller?

Comment: yes data.js is a factory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69146/discussion-between-vimes1984-and-stefanos-chrs).

Comment: because people apply downvotes very very liberally on this site don't pay attention to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot searching and frustration without result, I managed to get it to work by changing

```
resolve:{
  dataPromise: function(data){
    return data.index();
  }
}
```

into

```
resolve:{
  dataPromise:['data', function(data){
    return data.index();
  }]
}
```